# Html Transistion lag only for the first time after reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

This is a gif of issue :  https://gifyu.com/image/DeGX

And my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Mrsheesh/dj1L3vhq/7

i am using xampp to host this page in locale
and even jsfiddle seems laggy.
I tried to remove the image, and it worked fine.

Is there a way to fix this, without remove the image?

**My code:**

```js
console.log("msg.js Loaded");

function show_msg() {
  document.querySelector(".box-msg").classList.add("active");
  document.querySelector(".bg-msg").classList.add("active");
}

function hide_msg() {
  document.querySelector(".box-msg").classList.remove("active");
  document.querySelector(".bg-msg").classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-msg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.bg-msg.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.box-msg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 550px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.box-msg.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box-msg .box-head {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: blue; */
}

/* ==================================Close Button================================= */
.box-msg .box-head .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-msg .box-head .close::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "\D7";
  /* use the hex value here... */
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ==================================Head IMG================================= */
.box-msg .box-head .background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300%;
  /* animation: 10s left_right forwards; */
}

@keyframes left_right {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

/* ==================================Head Title================================= */
.box-msg .box-head .title {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(10px, 4vw, 35px);
  /* line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: BebasNeue-Regular;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* ====================================MSG Body================================= */
.box-msg .box-body {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: brown; */
}

/* ======================================BTN===================================== */
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: coral;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" onclick="show_msg()">Test</div>
<div class="bg-msg"></div>
<div class="box-msg">
  <div class="box-head">
    <div class="background">
      <img src="./img/background/bg2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="close" onclick="hide_msg()">Close</div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="body-text">Body Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag since the question has nothing to do with it. For future reference, only add tags that are relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. I tried your posted code in the stack snippet and the jsfiddle. So it should be something outside the posted/fiddled code...

Comment: Have you tried different browser? I'm unable reproduce it either.

Comment: sorry guys for my english: 
and thanks Erik for updating my question.
My issue is the lag as you can see in the gif

Comment: As i said if i remove the image the site will not lag. So i think the problem is the image file